# Send string from the client to the server with http (no sockets) in python

Tags: python, http, server, client, send

I've built a server-client structure with the http library (python) in which the client calls a listening server. It works like this:

- The client calls the server
- The server asks for a string
- Given the string, the server calls a scraper that extracts the information.
- The information is returned to the client.

The thing is that the server has to ask for the string. The client should send the string and the server should receive it. How is it possible to do it via http.client/http.server?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using WebSockets.

Comment: I agree, I started using WebSockets. But my boss wants it made with http so...

Comment: I've tried to change the method from GET to POST and send the string through the body (conn.request(method="POST", url='127.0.0.1', body="aapl")) but I don't know how to retrieve it from the server.

Comment: The server can't ask for something with HTTP, it's all driven by client requests.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The way the server "requested" something is a variable that I provided via terminal (an input). 
I know this is a bad practice, that's why I wanted to know how to do it better.
I've managed to do it with the comment that I posted before: Changed the method to POST and got the body via rfile.read